# JavaScript: TypeError cant read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, web

I am getting error while running this code , it's saying typeerror cant read property to 'lowercase' of undefined.
Code:-

```js
const notes = [{},{
    title: "My next Trip",
    body: "I would like to go to USA"
},{
    title: "Habbits to work on",
    body: "Exercise"
} ,{
    title: "Office Modification",
    body: "Get a new seat"
} ]

 const findNote = function(notes, noteTitle) {
     const index = notes.findIndex(function (note , index) {
         return note.title.toLowercase() ===  noteTitle.toLowerCase()
     })
     return notes[index]
 }
const note = findNote(notes, "Office Modification")
console.log(note);
```

Comment: The first item in your `notes` array is an empty object for some reason. Also, capitalization (usually) matters in programming.

Comment: its due to your empty object , its tyring to read note.title.toLowercase() but note.title is undefined

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 errors in the code

- Javascript is case sensitive - the correct function is `toLowerCase`
- There is an empty object which does not have `title` property - you need to add safe check for that in code

You can try following

```js
const notes = [{},{
    title: "My next Trip",
    body: "I would like to go to USA"
},{
    title: "Habbits to work on",
    body: "Exercise"
} ,{
    title: "Office Modification",
    body: "Get a new seat"
} ]

 const findNote = function(notes, noteTitle) {
     const index = notes.findIndex(function (note , index) {
         return note.title && note.title.toLowerCase() ===  noteTitle.toLowerCase()
     })
     return notes[index]
 }
const note = findNote(notes, "Office Modification")
console.log(note);
```